# update value on button single click

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, uialertview

I am new to IOS i need to display when button clicked single time my updated data displayed in alert view.My problem double click on button only its update my data in alert view but nslog its displayed correct manner but i failed in button action.

Button action coding:

```
- (IBAction)buttonaction1:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Amount"
                                                    message:final
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Book Now"
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];

    alert.tag = 100;
    [alert show];

    amountstr = amountTxt.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",amountstr);
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"type=%@&flag_id=%@&value=%@",typestr,idstr,amountstr];

    [self sendDataToServer :@"POST" params:str];

}
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView.tag == 100)
    {


         if (buttonIndex == 0)
         {

         }else
         {
         // cancel button pressed
         }
    }
}
```

Connection did finish loading delegates:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{


    NSError* error111;
    json111 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: mutableData
                                              options:kNilOptions
                                                error:&error111];


    NSLog(@"%@",json111);
    //NSDictionary *fetchDict = [json111 objectAtIndex:0];
    total = [json111 objectForKey:@"Total"];
    final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",total];
    NSLog(@"%@",final);
}
```

Post method to passing str string :
coding:

```
-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method params:(NSString *)str{

    NSData *postData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[str length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];


    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( theConnection ){

        mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your query?? unclear question it is!! what is `final` ? what you want exactly ?

Comment: here final only i fetch value from website that value can be displayed in alert view using button click @Lion

Comment: while i click button twice time only my updated value can displayed in alert view thats my query@Lion

Comment: what  happen if you press button only ones ? alert view is displayed ? if displayed what is title and message of it? and what is `final` parameter as message ?

Comment: press only one time means null value or previous value will show after change value@Lion

Comment: single press alert view will appear with title "amount" and message "null" @Lion

Comment: You set message `final`. what is this final? i am asking third time!!! what is final and from where you get value to this final ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111732/discussion-between-a-sonu-and-lion).

Comment: final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",total];
    NSLog(@"%@",final); here" final" string in (connectiondidfinishloading) can passing in alert view@Lion

Comment: your final string get value after webservice call is done. you are displaying it in alert view before it get any value. check my answer

Comment: ya i worked your  code but i need alert view after button pressed@Lion

Comment: in action method first call `sendDataToServer` method and then make alert view

Comment: check update in answer. But i think it will also shows null because final will take some time to get value because it comes from server

Comment: no change same null value after double click only value update in alert view  @Lion

Comment: but in Nslog its updated in single-click@Lion

Comment: yes because it printing from `connectionDidFinishLoading:` method which is get called after response is coming. try to print final from ibaction method before alertview it will show null

Comment: then i want to print final in ibaction@Lion

Comment: not understand your comment!! your English is too much bad!

Comment: try to print final from ibaction method before alertview it will show null this line only i am asking @Lion

Comment: yes that i have said early that you are trying to display null string. thats why i was asking earlier that what is fina!! so, final string get value after web service call so you can display it after web service call only. nothing else

Comment: k fine then to recover my problem @Lion

Comment: ypur problem is resolved or not sister

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like

```
  @interface CreateCatrgeringCustomerViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
  {
  NSString *currencyIDe1, *currencyIDe2, *amountType,*BranchIdes;
   NSString *btnSelectType;
   }
```

On your ViewDidload

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad]; 
 // for hold the initial value do like
  BranchIdes = (NSString *)[arrmsg1 objectAtIndex:0];
  currencyIDe1 = (NSString *)[id1 objectAtIndex:0];
   currencyIDe2 = (NSString *)[id2 objectAtIndex:0];

   btnSelectType = @"no";
 }
- (IBAction)buttonaction1:(id)sender {

 btnSelectType = @"yes";

amountstr = amountTxt.text;
NSLog(@"%@",amountstr);
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"type=%@&flag_id=%@&value=%@",typestr,idstr,amountstr];

[self sendDataToServer :@"POST" params:str];

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{


NSError* error111;
json111 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: mutableData
                                       options:kNilOptions
                                         error:&error111];
NSLog(@"%@",json111);

  if (json111)
  {
    if ([btnSelectType isEqualToString:@"yes"])
    {

   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Amount"
                                                message:final
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Book Now"
                                      otherButtonTitles: nil];

  alert.tag = 100;
  [alert show];

     }

}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (alertView.tag == 100)
{

  btnSelectType = @"no";

}
}
```

Comment: ya its update my value but i need alert view will come after button click@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: no change double click only value can update in alert view @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: ya i check and tell u bro@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @A.sonu - sure, i will support

Comment: finally with your help i got solution to my problem@Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0):

white your code alert view code in `connectionDidFinishLoading` method instead of action method. like,

```
 -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 {


NSError* error111;
json111 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: mutableData
                                          options:kNilOptions
                                            error:&error111];


NSLog(@"%@",json111);
//NSDictionary *fetchDict = [json111 objectAtIndex:0];
total = [json111 objectForKey:@"Total"];
final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",total];
NSLog(@"%@",final);

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Amount"
                                                message:final
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Book Now"
                                      otherButtonTitles: nil];

alert.tag = 100;
[alert show];
}
```

**Update :**

```
 - (IBAction)buttonaction1:(id)sender {

amountstr = amountTxt.text;
NSLog(@"%@",amountstr);
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"type=%@&flag_id=%@&value=%@",typestr,idstr,amountstr];

[self sendDataToServer :@"POST" params:str];

 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Amount"
                                                message:final
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Book Now"
                                      otherButtonTitles: nil];

alert.tag = 100;
[alert show];


 }
```